# Implementing IEnumerable for generic tree c#

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I have a generic tree class, for which I want to implement the IEnumerable interface. The previous questions I found on stackoverflow were a bit different from my problem. I know that I am doing something wring but I don't know what it is. Here is my code:

```
class Node<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T data;
    private LinkedList<Node<T>> children;

    public Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        children = new LinkedList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public void AddChildNode(Node<T> node)
    {
        children.AddFirst(node);
    }

    public void MyTraverse(Node<T> node, List<T> visited)
    {
        visited.Add(node.data);
        foreach (Node<T> kid in node.children)
            MyTraverse(kid, visited);

    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return children.GetEnumerator();
    }


    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

In the function GetEnumerator() I get a casting error which I don't know how to fix. Can any one help me?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Error msg: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<Microsoft_Example_Added.Node<T>>.Enumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' D:\BoxSync\amirho\Categories\Implementation\SAT_Solvers\Z3\Microsoft_Example_Added\Microsoft_Example_Added\Node.cs 35 20 Microsoft_Example_Added

Comment: Adding the T in the signature does not solve the problem!

Comment: One thing is getting the method to compile, another is to make it do what you want. **What do you want it to do and to return?** To make it compile simply do `return children.Select(node => node.data);` but I doubt this will give you what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get Enumerator is like ::

```
 public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return children.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `IEnumerable<Node<T>>` interface implementation (you're enumerating *nodes* `Node<T>`, not `T` instances) instead of just `IEnumerable<T>` one:

```
 class Node<T>: IEnumerable<Node<T>> {
   ...
    public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator() {
      return children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `children` is defined like this:

```
private LinkedList<Node<T>> children;
```

which means that `children` is `IEnumerable<Node<T>>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Since you want it as `IEnumerable<T>` you have to extract the `data` member. Going to by how your traversal method is defined I also suspect you want it to recursively descend into nodes children:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return data;
    foreach (var childNode in children)
        foreach (var child in childNode)
            yield return child;
}
```

If you only want it to return the children, use this code:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return children.Select(node => node.data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Node : IEnumerable<Node>
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public string Value { get; internal set; }

    public Node Parent { get; internal set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; internal set; }

    public Node(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(Name)}");

        Name = name;
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var self = this;
        var queue = new Queue<Node>();
        queue.Enqueue(self);

        while (queue.Any())
        {
            yield return queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var child in self.Children)
                queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }             
}
```

Also, this is also works, and less code:

```
     public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var self = this;
        yield return self;

        foreach (var child in self.Children)
            yield return child;
    }
```